# Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details)

Tags: facebook, share

I just wanted to share pages which address includes query strings.but og:image does not shown albeit image:url is absolutely correct.
facebook debugger shows error as the title I wrote.I dont understand what is wrong and how to solve it.I can share link but without image albeit og:image meta tag is absolutely linked to a correct image.

this is the page :
http://www.mysite.com/Pages/EtkinlikDetay.aspx?ID=In6EP/AKxcU=

and og tags are these which I m generating them on asp.net page_load procedure.
what makes it so hard to share a page link on facebook ? and can you give us a solid solution how to fix this ? ı can prepare s small project asp.net to reproduce for you to detect problem. or can you say this is a bug ?
(thanks for any comments)

> > meta property="og:site_name" content="Web Site Name 1" />
> >     meta property="og:title" content="Mutfak Sanatları Akademisi" />
> >     meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/Pages/EtkinlikDetay.aspx?ID=In6EP/AKxcU=" />
> >     meta property="og:description" content="my description 1" />
> >     meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/Upload/Etkinlikler/falanca/vazgecemediklerimiz.jpg" />

Answer (score 0):

i faced the cirular redirect path problem 
so i used urlencode 
and it worked

```
       meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo urldecode(http://www.mysite.com/Pages/EtkinlikDetay.aspx?ID=In6EP/AKxcU=);?>" />
```